# programmatically run JUnit tests

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I have a *.class file that a contains the class that I want to test and a *.class file contains the JUnit test. I need to programmatically run the tests. Anyone have any ideas where to start?

Actually with a JarCreator launched by a ShellCommandRunner, I create the JarFile of the .Class File I want to test.

Then with the directory of the JarFile Just created and the directory of the class that contains Junit test I launch by command line the JunitRunner.jar (located in the Java Folder)
This execution gives me a Stdout result (in a String).

All I want is to avoid to use the a ShellCommandRunner and to get the test result by a Junit Executor in Eclipse starting from the directory of the .class File to be tested and the directory of the Junit test that tests that class and to get the result in a String and , if it is possible avoid to create a jar File to be created before starting the test.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? It sounds at this point like you're in need of Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Is writing a [test suite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_suite_test.htm) an option? Eclipse also has [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm) therefore. This way you can also skip the JAR generation

Comment: yes it could be a hopeful option but I really want to take the directory of the class that i want to test and the directory of the class that contains the the junit test,test that class and get a String result of the method tested that tells me how many tests are failed in that class
for now I can test  the class passing the two directories and the directory of the junit runner on a shell command runner 
i want to avoid to use the shell command runner and do it by eclipse but i dont know how
@RomanVottner  chyrils

Comment: Instead of using a plain JUnit suite you can also use a [DirectorySuiteBuilder](http://junit.org/junit4/faq.html#running_15) or a [WildcardPatternSuite](https://junit-toolbox.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/googlecode/junittoolbox/WildcardPatternSuite.html) to execute all tests from certain (sub)directories

Comment: The processing of failed, succeeded, starting or finished tests can be done using [TestWatchman](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatchman.html)